# Issue in using hadoop fs -put command in python code to transfer file from local filesystem to hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am using this code in python which reads records from a file, does some processing on them and then write the outcome to a new file.Then I transfer the file from my local filesystem to hdfs:

```
read = open('file_read.txt', 'r')

for line in read:
    fields = line.split('|')
    columns.append(fields)

category = [-1,1,2,3,4,5,6]
out = open('file_write.txt', 'w')

for line in columns:
    out.write('{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}'.format(line[0], line[1], line[5], line[6].rstrip().replace('-','')))
    for val in category:
        if int(line[4]) == val:
            out.write('|{0}'.format(line[2]))
        else:
            out.write('|')
    for val in category:
        if int(line[4]) == val:
            out.write('|{0}'.format(line[3]))
        else:
            out.write('|')
    out.write('\n')
str = "HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hadoop fs -put file_write.txt /folder1/folder2/"
result = system(str)
```

The problem is that during the transfer some of the last few records are getting lost from the file. The file that gets moved to hdfs has about 10 records less than the file which is on my local file system. I have tried `-moveFromLocal` also but same result occurs. Though if I execute the any of the above command from the terminal then complete file gets moved but its just when I am executing it from within a python script the issue comes.

Why is this issue coming and what could I do to resolve it?

**UPDATE:** The issue of missing records are coming only if I execute the part above the `hadoop fs - put` command. If I do not execute it and just move simple file then there is no loss of data occurring. I have tried to see if there any special character that is getting inserted and which may be causing the loss of last few records but couldn't find one (I tried to look for them by going through the file).

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the issue.

```
$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc "\n [:alnum:]" | head -c10000000 > test.txt
$ cat python_hdfs.py 
from os import system

str = "HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hadoop fs -put test.txt /tmp/"
print system(str)
$ cat test.txt | wc -l
155682
$ python python_hdfs.py 
0
$ hadoop fs -cat /tmp/test.txt | wc -l
155682
```

Maybe config related?

- Is the exit status of the system call 0? Are you on linux or windows?
- How big is the file? Does it happen only with this specific one, or other files as well?

Comment: Yes the exit status of the system call is 0. I am executing this on linux and the file has about 161014 records (around 7.7 mb). The file that gets copied has 25 rows less. Are there any other ways (apart from `systems()`) that achieve the same purpose?

Comment: There is. Try using subprocess.call 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: can you show how I can I use subprocess to execute the above command?

Comment: if you add 

    `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs`

to your .bashrc, you don't have to define it before every command.
You can use subprocess.call like this: 
    `subprocess.call("hadoop fs -put test.txt /tmp", shell=True)`

Comment: if I don't add it to my .bashrc then the code should be `subprocess.call("HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hadoop fs -put test.txt /tmp", shell=True)` correct?

Comment: No. Same output. Still last few records getting deleted while moving to hdfs

Comment: Is there any config setting that puts restriction on the size of the file that can be moved?

Comment: There are name and space quotas in hadoop, but that should not be the issue as the hadoop fs command is working from cli. You have not answered if it happens only with this specific file, or others too. Did you try the testfile?

Comment: Yes it is happening with other files as well. Is there any other way through which I can copy/move a local file to hdfs?

Comment: There is an additional code part in my script which does some processing and produces the file which is then transferred to hdfs. I have uppdated my post above to include that processing. The issue of missing records are coming only if I execute the part above the `hadoop fs - put` command. If I do not execute it and just move simple file then there is no loss of data occurring.